# How do I setup my Kedei 3.5 touchscreen on my Raspberry Pi 2 model B?

Tags: touchscreen, setup

I got a Raspberry Pi for my birthday and I have no idea how to set up the touchscreen. I have looked at other tutorials to set the touchscreen up but none of the ones I found support my touchscreen. Please help me figure this out I'm a complete noob to the Raspberry Pi world.

Specs:
Raspberry Pi 2 Model B
 Touchscreen- Kedei 3.5 inch SPI TFTLCD  480*320 16bit/18bit Version 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Here is an open source driver for this display on pi.

https://github.com/kpishere/fbcp-ili9341.git

Answer (score 1):

i also started with the pi.
i've got pi3 model b and the same display with version 6.2
on http://kedei.net/ you'll find a complete linux image.

i installed it on a sd card, put the display onto the pi and everything works fine ... 
best regard
olaf

Answer (score 0):

Try this GitHub post if you haven't had any luck: https://github.com/kedei/LCD_driver/issues/5

That's the official repo for the KeDei model.